# Use MailChimp or Rails Website to send Newsletter to customers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp, sendgrid, newsletter

Is it worth the time and effort to create a feature on our rails website to send emails to our customer database once a week, or is MailChimp the almighty One to use to send weekly newsletters to thousands of people?  If we used our rails application could SenderGrid or some other feature be an option for our newsletter?

We currently use Mailchimp and we love it but the owner of the company wants the website to do everything for us in one simple place.

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: You can use [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com). It is part of MailChimp so you can import your templates from MailChimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wants the website to do everything for us in one simple place.

In that case, it's not a question of "Mailchimp or bust", it's a question of [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer).

Specifically, the owner will probably want a central "dashboard" on his web dashboard (kind of like how CRM works), from which he'll be able to see how many members, emails etc have been sent out.

---

As such, I'd endeavour to use [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/?awid=75079134&awag=21582983574&awad=79443922974&awkw=mandrill&pid=GAW&source=website&gclid=CjwKEAjwzJexBRCa_pGo8IK0ilASJABfGldbGyVvTyrtF3xYrWtLMunW2EEMzSQ5u5BkHzOy9dqcahoCI-Dw_wcB) and collate the data in the app, like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :mailouts
   has_many :newsletters, through: :mailouts
end

#app/models/mailout.rb
class Mailout < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | user_id | newsletter_id | created_at | updated_at | sent_at | received_at
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :newsletter
end

#app/models/newsletter.rb
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | title | body | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :mailouts
   has_many :users, through: :mailouts

   after_create :set_mailouts

   private

   def set_mailouts
      User.find_each do |user|
        self.mailouts.create(user: user)
      end
   end
end
```

This would give you the ability to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/newsletters_controller.rb
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @newsletter = Newsletter.new
   end

   def create
      @newsletter = Newsletter.new newsletter_params
      @newsletter.save
   end
end
```

Quite inefficient with the `after_create`, but nonetheless it shows that you can then have a rake task which would do something like this:

```
@newsletter = Newsletter.find x
@newsletter.mailouts.each do |mailout|
   # send mailout to mandrill
end
```

---

Something important to remember is that *Mandrill* and *SendGrid* are **infrastructure** applications. Mailchimp itself provides UI functionality on top of the Mandrill infrastructure.

If you were looking to use the likes of Mailchimp, what you'd probably end up doing is sending the user list to Mailchimp each week, allowing you to send newsletters through their system.

Creating your own functionality & linking to Mandrill will only change your implementation by giving you the ability to manage the data on your own application. Just something to remember when thinking about the structure.

Comment: Excellent response/answer!  Thank  you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Without a third-party like Mailchimp or SenderGrid, you're going to have to do a lot of work to handle unsubscribe functionality and analytics (bounces, opens, clicks...) etc. If you don't handle unsubscribes appropriately, your company can get in substantial legal trouble. You're also going to need to set-up a proper email server somehow, because using Rails' ActionMailer without SMTP configuration is going to have horrible delivery rates (email clients will interpret your sends as spoofed emails).

If you want your website to handle the logic of email newsletter scheduling, you can build the logic into your website and have the website communicate with Mailchimp (for example) through the API to schedule sends and handle unsubscribes that way. You can also retrieve campaign stats through the API, and write it back to your website database or whatever. That may be worth the effort, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Excellent points on the legal side of things and having to do a lot of work!  Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Give [MailyHerald](http://mailyherald.org) a try. It is a Rails engine that will help you manage your newsletters and provide you with nice web ui. It also works with Mandrill and other email services.